# Non-mod-only tag is shown in red

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

Last I checked, one did not need a diamond in their name to post questions tagged [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity). I also didn't know that main site tags could be mods-only.

[image: Screenshot (also shows my browser)]

Oddly enough, when I'm in the editor it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a red tag; a red tag would have a red font on a pink background, like the tag below.

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

The copper font in your image indicates a visited link, meaning you have been to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity.

If you click on [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) and check this post again, their colors should change from gray to copper as well.

Comment: Ah, colorblind. [meta-tag:status-bydesign] or [meta-tag:status-norepro]?

Comment: I guess norepro fits a bit better. I mainly included it to show an example.

Comment: @StephenLeppik [I brought up the issue of colorblindness wrt tags on Mother Meta a few months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280672/307833). I've found that using the userscript I wrote greatly improves contrast. FWIW, the visited tag does look a lot like a mod-only tag to me, too.